# How to make error messages disappear quicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, error-handling

Here is a minor bug that is bothersome. The error validation message takes too long (about 3 seconds) to disappear after a valid input has been made. Here is an example.

[image]

Are there any tricks to make this problem go away? Is there a way to make the browser tab to the next field right away after an valid selection? This was not a problem before I changed the custom error message.

**Plunker with this problem**: https://plnkr.co/edit/oKYX6iUC6avbvfELjxWs?p=preview

The only solution I can think of now is

```
element.next().focus()
```

Comment: I don't think it takes three seconds to be disappeared. Can you please add any Fiddle/Plnkr with your code?

Comment: you can bind to `oninput` events, and check for validation, and if valid focus on the next element in your form.

Comment: @KhalidHussain I used the example from your Plnkr from the other question

Comment: @mani thank you I will give it a shot

Comment: @jebmarcus Where is the plnkr link? Does this delay happen for all `HTML5` validation? You did not provide any code in your question body. It is not easy to answer any question only by looking at snapshot.

Comment: @KhalidHussain Plunker has been added, you can see the problem I described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cases when `HTML5` validation message is disappeared for a required field:

**Case 1**: If you enter any valid input in required field, `HTML5`  validation message will be disappeared. ([Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mxgKDPdq9FJUIyassKJ?p=preview))

**Case 2**: Even if you do not enter any input,  `HTML5` validation message will be disappeared after few seconds.(Check with the `Plnkr` of `case 1`)

In your code, when you click on `Submit`, `ValidateInput()` method is called which sets custom validation message.

This validation message can be disappered in `2` ways.

1. Usual way (Described in `case 2`)
2. With valid input, by clicking on `submit` button.

As you have modified the default validation message in `ValidateInput()` method, so default behavior of `HTML5` validation message (`case 1`) will not work. If you remove `ValidateInput()` method, it will work as expected ([Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tskpSm8Qr45vrwLDvJ1X?p=preview)).

```
    <form name='serviceForm'>
      <select id='colorId1' ng-model = "color1" class = "form-control"
          ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" required>

          <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
      </select><br><br>

      <select id='colorId2' ng-model = "color2" class = "form-control"
          ng-options = "color as color for color in colors"  required>

          <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
      </select><br><br>

      <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
   </form>
```

Hope that answer your question.

**Solution based on the comment of jebmarcus:**

Yes, there is a way to achieve this with your custom message. You just need to call `ValidateInput()` method on `change` event of both `drop-down`.

[Working Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vQbHtGGMKLgh9ovFAU2W?p=preview)

```
<form name='serviceForm'>
      <select ng-change='ValidateInput()' id='colorId1' ng-model = "color1" class = "form-control"
          ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" required>

          <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
      </select><br><br>

      <select ng-change='ValidateInput()' id='colorId2' ng-model = "color2" class = "form-control"
          ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" required>

          <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
      </select><br><br>

      <input type='submit' ng-click='ValidateInput()' value='Submit'>
   </form>
```

Comment: right exactly. Sorry if my question was unclear but I was wondering how do I get the message to disappear right away with ValidateInput() as if it weren't there

Comment: I have tested this before, yes if I remove the custom messages in ValidateInput(), the messages disappear right away. Is there a way to achieve this with my custom message? Thank you